# Difficult to complete a tough query script for me

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pervasive

```
    SELECT a.acikkapali, 
    b.onay, b.evrakno, 
    b.tarih,  
    a.kod, 
    d.ad, 
    a.note0, 
    a.sf_miktar, 
    a.sf_sf_unit, 
    a.rtalepedilentestarih, 
    c.evrakno
FROM stok47T a 
LEFT JOIN stok47e b on a.evrakno = b.evrakno
LEFT JOIN stok46t1 c on a.evrakno = c.talepno
LEFT JOIN stok00 d on a.kod = d.kod
WHERE a.tarih = '2013/04/15'
```

I need to add two my tables into that script with right way that means If I mapped one of them then the normal row count increases this makes me crazy, I have been trying to solve that issue for a couple days but I had been fail many times.
I couldn't find a good mapped fields between stok47t and the others. But there are still a few columns(fields) matches for their types and data.
I need to listen ppl opinions and learns something.

[Here is a big part of my query](http://imageshack.us/a/img812/3705/seriousissue.png)

Comment: What do you see in my question that makes it understandable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting increase in row count then chances are it could be due to using LEFT JOIN. An INNER join might help (see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html guidance)

```
SELECT a.acikkapali, 
b.onay, b.evrakno, 
b.tarih,  
a.kod, 
d.ad, 
a.note0, 
a.sf_miktar, 
a.sf_sf_unit, 
a.rtalepedilentestarih, 
c.evrakno
FROM stok47T a 
INNER JOIN stok47e b on a.evrakno = b.evrakno
INNER JOIN stok46t1 c on a.evrakno = c.talepno
INNER JOIN stok00 d on a.kod = d.kod
WHERE a.tarih = '2013/04/15'
```

However without understanding your data structure then there is a chance you might lose the information that you are after.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting multiple rows, it is probably due to a Cartesian product occurring in the joins.  This is unrelated to the type of join (left/right/full/inner).  It is based on the relationships between the tables.  You have 1-N relationships along different dimensions.

Your conditions are:

```
FROM stok47T a 
LEFT JOIN stok47e b on a.evrakno = b.evrakno
LEFT JOIN stok46t1 c on a.evrakno = c.talepno
LEFT JOIN stok00 d on a.kod = d.kod
```

I have no idea what these tables and fields mean.  But, if you have a case where there is one row per `evrakno` in table `stok47t`, and there are two rows in table `stok47e` and three in table `stok46t1`, then you will get six rows in the output.

Without more information, it is impossible to tell you the best solution.  One method is to summarize the tables.  Another is to take the first or last corresponding row, by doing something like:

```
from stok47T a left join
     (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by evrakno order by id desc) as seqnum
      from stok47e s
     ) b
     on a.evrakno = b.evrakno and b.seqnum = 1
```

Comment: I just found a chance to write back something, sorry for late reply. Now I am starting to put some instance of all those 6 tables

Comment: It's ready difficult to share all those fields which it has contains so many columns each table :(